# Xamarin.Forms maps on MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I want to use maps with MVVMCross. In iOS everything is OK, but in Android I don't have Bundle in the OnCreate() method, so I don't know where I should initialize `Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);`

My MainApplication.cs looks like this:

```
public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
      : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services!
    }

    public override void OnTerminate()
    {
        base.OnTerminate();

        UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

    }

    public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
    {

    }

    public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
    {

    }

    public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
    {

    }

    public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
    {

    }
}
```

I don't know if I have to create another view or something like that.
Any thoughs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, You can override the onCreate Method that will accept the instance details.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init (this, bundle);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change the extended classes in order to do that.